# How to block audio output for an application in Pulseaudio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone, zoom-meeting

I have a question. Turns out I use Zoom for video conferencing. Now when I share a video, **Zoom** changes the output of all the programs to "zoom_combine_device" so that the audio is output from the computer, and when the video is finished it returns to the default output of my card.

Now, there is a program that I need to never change (pulseeffects, which I need to always be in the output of "PulseEffects (mic)" **How can I block it so that Zoom or anyone else changes the source of that output?**

Thank you!!! and sorry if I did not use the correct technical terms XD

Answer (score 0):

Go into Settings, into the Applications item in the left-hand column, and select Zoom (if you installed the app). The `Play Audio` option should be there.